# Output form results on same page

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to display form results on the same page as the form but when I click my "Get Total" button I see the result appear briefly then disappear. My result is off too, I'm trying to add my variables together but I'm getting a join instead.

```
<form id="percentageBiz" method="post">
<input type="text" id="sum1">
<input type="text" id="sum2">
<input type="submit" onclick="total()" value="Get Total">

<div id="display" style="height: 50px; width: 100%;"></div>

<script>
function total(){
    var a = document.forms["percentageBiz"]["sum1"].value;
    var b = document.forms["percentageBiz"]["sum2"].value;
    //alert(a+b)
    var display=document.getElementById("display")
    display.innerHTML=a+b;
}
</script>
```

Comment: Try parsing the variables `a` and `b` before adding them together [String to Number convertion](http://www.javascripter.net/faq/convert2.htm). And add a `return false` at the end, if I'm not mistaken this will prevent the submit from happening.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's flashing because you're not doing anything to stop the form from submitting, and concatenating because you're not casting the values as numbers. Note you can use [parseFloat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat) if you're dealing with non-integers instead of [parseInt](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt) as I used below.

Try this **[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/mw6FB/)**.

```
function total(){
    var a = document.forms["percentageBiz"]["sum1"].value;
    var b = document.forms["percentageBiz"]["sum2"].value;
    //alert(a+b)
    var display=document.getElementById("display")
    display.innerHTML=parseInt(a,10)+parseInt(b,10);
    return false;
}​
```

and

```
<form id="percentageBiz" method="post">
<input type="text" id="sum1">
<input type="text" id="sum2">
<input type="submit" onclick="return total()" value="Get Total">
</form>
<div id="display" style="height: 50px; width: 100%;"></div>​
```

Comment: I don't really like `onclick`.

Answer (score 4):

"the result appears briefly then disappears."

1. Try using input type="***button***" rather than input type="***submit***".
2. OR Else ( while using input type="submit" )   avoid form submission,  by *returning **false***  in  *function total()* and put *onclick="**return total( )**"*.

Answer (score 1):

what's happening is your javascript code is working, but then submit is executing. All you need to do is switch type='submit' to type='button' and the reason you are getting the two numbers joining together is because it doesn't understand if it's a string or a number, so if you put display.innerHTML=parseInt(a + b); instead of display.innerHTML=a + b; it should solve your other problem.

Comment: Your right I didn't see the other part. He also needs to do display.innerHTML=parseInt(a + b);

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to add two strings together. You should parse them into integers first:
http://www.javascripter.net/faq/convert2.htm

```
    <form id="percentageBiz" method="post">
<input type="text" id="sum1">
<input type="text" id="sum2">
<input type="submit" onclick="total()" value="Get Total">

<div id="display" style="height: 50px; width: 100%;"></div>

<script>
function total(){
    var a = parseInt(document.forms["percentageBiz"]["sum1"].value);
    var b = parseInt(document.forms["percentageBiz"]["sum2"].value);
    //alert(a+b)
    var display=document.getElementById("display")
    display.innerHTML=a+b;
}
</script>
```

You shouldn't multiply them by 1 to cast, because that is parsing the string into an integer AND multiplying it by 1. So it's an extra step.

Comment: http://jsperf.com/number-cast -- If you go for speed, use `parseFloat`. It beats `parseInt` 2:1; `parseInt` beats the rest 2:1 as well. Unary plus should be the fastest but it's not. Unary plus still wins in consciseness and readability. As far as int-casts go, I'm impressed that `~~` is faster than `|0`. As far as Firefox goes,  everything performs the same.

Comment: OK... parseFloat rocks in V8, parseInt = unary plus, V8 is slow in *1, I'm impressed `~~` outperforms `|0` slightly. In FF, parseInt is better than the rest, which is all the same.

Answer (score 0):

You get a join instead of a sum because you always get String values.

You can multiply them by 1 for example, then you're var will be treaded as a number.